# Java 8 Stream API Collector - addAll not applicable for argument Object, addAll is undefined for type Object

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

My code is not compiling and I'm not quite sure why. Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<ClassificationData> classifications = productData
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(p.getClassifications()))
                .flatMap(p -> p.getClassifications().stream())
                .collect(groupingBy(ClassificationData::getName,
                        mapping(ClassificationData::getFeatures,
                                Collector.of(LinkedHashSet<FeatureData>::new,
                                        (a,b) -> b.addAll(a),
                                        (a,b) -> {
                                            b.addAll(a);
                                            return b;
                                        })
                        )))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    ClassificationData c = new ClassificationData();
                    c.setName(e.getKey());
                    c.setFeatures(e.getValue());
                    return c;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

And the errors:

```
    (a,b) -> b.addAll(a),
The method addAll(Collection<? extends FeatureData>) in the type Collection<FeatureData> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

     b.addAll(a);
The method addAll(Object) is undefined for the type Object

     c.setFeatures(e.getValue());
The method setFeatures(Collection<FeatureData>) in the type ClassificationData is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

I've also tried Set::add and Set::addAll with pretty much the same result.

EDIT:

I've ended up with this code. Please tell me if there is a cleaner way to do this, or is it ok?

```
ArrayList<ClassificationData> classifications = productData
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(p.getClassifications()))
                .flatMap(p -> p.getClassifications().stream())
                .collect(groupingBy(ClassificationData::getName,
                        mapping(ClassificationData::getFeatures,
                                toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)
                        )))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    ClassificationData c = new ClassificationData();
                    c.setCode(e.getKey());
                    c.setName(e.getKey());
                    c.setFeatures(e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
                            .flatMap(p -> p.stream())
                            .filter(distinctByKey(FeatureData::getName))
                            .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
                    return c;
                })
                .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: I suggest you add some type information to give yourself hints as the cause of the type confusion could be anywhere in this code. Most likely you have a raw type somewhere.

Comment: Your solution incorporates potentially expensive hashing of `Set`s and might require more temporary memory. Your original code works fine with `javac` and appropriate declarations of `ClassificationData` and `FeatureData`. Either, the definitions of `ClassificationData` and `FeatureData`, which you didn’t show, have problems, or you are using Eclipse, which sometimes has problems with the type inference.

Comment: @Holger I'm using Oracle Java 8. Both `ClassificationData` and `FeatureData` are autogenerated DTO's so I can't really do much about them. Used fields are `Collection<ClassificationData> classifications;` and`Collection<FeatureData> features;` That's the problem I've tried to describe with oversimplified example of Car in other thread, which you've responded to.

Comment: You might not be able to change the autogenerated classes, but knowing the exact signatures might help us finding out, why your first attempt failed. As said, with straight-forward declarations, it works, so there must be a difference…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the order of the arguments messed up in the first lambda; it should be

```
(set, a) -> set.add(a)
```

...though frankly it'd be better just to replace the entire Collector creation with

```
toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)
```

Which is equivalent.

Comment: I've tried it both ways. This ends up with different error message
`The method addAll(Collection<FeatureData>) is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: Did you try the toCollection approach?  And did you try including explicit types for all your lambda parameters everywhere?

Comment: Both lambdas have their parameters swapped.

Comment: toCollection results in creating Set of Collections which is not really what I want to acomplish.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think I've managed to achieve what I wanted following your advice. I'll update main post with the code I have for now, so you can maybe tell me if there is a way to make it cleaner or should we call it a day.